# Sidekiq - could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, concurrency, sidekiq

I get the following warning with Rails 4 and Sidekiq on os x on development

```
10:13:39 worker.1 | 2014-09-22T07:13:39.857Z 86981 TID-oug0oog10 WARN: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.002 seconds)
10:13:39 worker.1 | 2014-09-22T07:13:39.857Z 86981 TID-oug0oog10 WARN: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `block in wait_poll'
```

I read other answers that say to reduce the concurrency I give to sidekiq to allow more for other things, but with

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 10
```

it still doesn't work

I am using Postgres.app

What should the numbers/concurrency be in localhost?

Comment: Are there errors in the PostgreSQL server error log? If so, what are they?

Comment: I only see the worker/sidekiq errors. where should I see the PG error log?

Comment: Exactly where it is depends on the operating system and how PostgreSQL is installed/configured. Look it up in the docs for your install, if you're stuck, search.

Comment: Postgres.app stores logs in /Users/YOUR_NAME/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.4/postgres-server.log file

Comment: @NickGinanto Any piece of news? I'm getting the same problem and want to know if this fix it, and the reasons

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I set database pool to sidekiq concurrency and now it works for me.

```
bundle exec sidekiq -c 10
```

in my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  ...
  host: localhost
  pool: 10
```

Comment: It seems to fixed my problem which I could not fix for a month of trials and errors. **madoxer** thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my problem

Comment: reducing the concurrent db might help

Comment: @JamesTan Why reducing the concurrent DB might help? I'm getting the same problem and not sure why it should help. Clearly, the #pooling > #threads.

Comment: @IgnacioChiazzo i think because there are either insufficient memory or postgresql connection limit

Answer (score 5):

The probem is related to the fact that database pool should be 'sidekiq_concurrency' + 2. If you put this into your sidekiq initializer you will solve the problem in general:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
     config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
         Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
     config['pool'] = Sidekiq.options[:concurrency] + 2
     ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
     Rails.logger.debug("Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server is now: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.instance_variable_get('@size')}")
end
```

Comment: could you give us further information? Why does the number 2? I am facing the same issue and not sure why it should fix the problem

Comment: This is related to this: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/4.0-Upgrade.md

Comment: seems to help. Thank you !

Comment: The "+ 2" is related to the Redis connections, not to the database connections. And now it's even "+ 5", see https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis#complete-control

Answer (score 1):

Database connection size should be one plus the concurrency if we are using rails < 5.2 . Here is the corresponding GitHub issue. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4252

If there are 5 threads then the db pool size should be 6 in rails < 5.2 version

Comment: Thanks! That was an issue in our codebase and I was able to reproduce and fix it due to your answer and issue. Also left a comment – https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4252#issuecomment-576583244 – which contains info regarding fixes in Rails 5.2