# Active Record Could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sidekiq

From the last few weeks, I am seeing this error "Could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds." I have tried the following solutions.

As per Sidekiq [Docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#cannot-get-database-connection-within-500-seconds) I have reduced the concurrency to 10 and increased MySql DB pool size to 12. But I was still getting this error so I increased the DB pool size to 27. But still, the issue is there. Tried solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41259300/4614833) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57882611/4614833) answer. My Sidekiq server machine doesn't have any other process running which can consume AR connections. I am not spinning any threads from outside. Below are the configurations I have

```
Sidekiq version - 3.4.2
Rails version - 4.2.4
Active Record version - 4.2.4
Database pool size - 27
Sidekiq concurrency - 10
```

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you hitting your mysql max total connections count? `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections"`, by default that's 151

Comment: @Vasfed I am not hitting max total connection. I have 10000 max connections available.

Comment: Please provide `GLOBAL STATUS` and `VARIABLES`.  Instructions: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: if connecting by hostname, is it some form of DNS failure (try connecting by IP).

Comment: It's not DNS failure. As far as I researched and googled, I am certain that this is something to do with ActiveRecord. Somehow connections are not getting checked out back to the connection pool.

Comment: I had this error a long time ago and this Heroku post was really helpful to understand my database connections restrictions: 

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

Comment: @pabloxio I tried that. I have even added the solutions I tried in question also. It's not working for me. I have even doubled the number of DB connections in the pool.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect it to be a connection leak from the server side.

`Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::ActiveRecord` is the middleware that is responsible for returning connections to the pool, after a job is completed. This should be included by default.

When you start your server with `-v` flag,

```
bundle exec sidekiq -v -C config_file
```

it will print all the middlewares that will be invoked. Can you check if this middleware is present in the list?

Comment: Yes it is present and I am also setting the connection pool in configuration as mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41259300/4614833 . I agree it's a possible connection leak. I have tried monitoring thread counts also, if somewhere any thread is holding up on a connection, but couldn't find much.